# Upload an app to GooglePlay without versionCode neither versionName?

Tags: android, apk

I thought it was not possible, but why mistake we were able to upload an apk to GooglePlay without VersionCode neither VersionName. If it's possible,  which is the version code the app is going to have?

Comment: the project was in built in eclipse or android studio?

Comment: If you were able to upload it then you should also be able to view the version in the play store developer console

Comment: last day i was uploading APK, but i forgot to change Version Code, and Google Account gave be Error for same version,then i update higher version then Google account gave permission to upload APK successfully.  i think its not Possible to upload APK without Version code..

Comment: Aditay Kaushal I know, the point is what happens if you don't add VersionCode or VersionName at all.

Comment: It was an Android Studio Project